# Prevent Highcharts to redraw Axis' scale

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent Highcharts from recalculating and redrawing the scale of the Axis when I add a new serie.
What I need to do is the following: I have a scatter chart with a lot of data; when the user selects a point, I add a new series with a "line" type. This series' points are a limited sample from the previous ones, so no "real" new points are added, but the scale of the xAxis changes.
Setting xAxis' min and max value, startOnTick and endOnTick to true did not solve the problem. Any idea?

---

Edit:
As I wrote, the way Highcharts handles axis' scales is still a mistery to me. In my case, I was rendering one scatter and one column graph on the same canvas. In response to a user click, I was adding 2 new series: a line serie and a column serie each one based on a subset of the original data. The problem was caused by the column graph: when you add a new serie to a column graph, bars are not overlapped, but redistributed, thus creating the scale change effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the line series but hidden, and when you want to show it use [chart.series[1].show()](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#series-object).

Comment: This is a great idea, thank you! I'll try and let you know. The way Highcharts handles axis' scales is still a mistery to me...

Comment: @simonelippolis Ok, after that please post here if it solved your problem.